# Android JNI GDB

Tags: android, gdb, java-native-interface

Does anybody have any truly smooth instructions on using GDB to debug JNI code on Android? So far all I've found is this ndk-gdb thing, but I really would rather stay away from the awful gdb command line interface.

Comment: I haven't tried it with the NDK but aren't there multiple frontends that you can attach to gdb even over a network?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Tegra based device, you might want to look at [TADP](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack).
It attempts to streamline development and debugging setup process for android, and has some custom-built debug bits (and docs).